# Literal SQL works: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to add an ARRAY to an existing jsonb ARRAY. This array will be added to the ARRAY[0] of the existing array. When I hardcode the details it's working but when I try to do it dynamically it fails with the above error. what am I doing wrong?

Postgresql 13 db server version

```
with whatposition as (select position pos from users cross join lateral 
jsonb_array_elements(user_details->'Profile') with ordinality arr(elem,position)
where display_ok=false)
update users set user_details=jsonb_set(
user_details,concat('ARRAY[''userProfile'',''',(select pos-1 from whatposition)::text,'''',',''DocumentDetails'']')::text[],
'[{"y":"supernewValue"}]')
where display_ok=false;
```

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal:
> "ARRAY['userProfile','0','DocumentDetails']"   Detail: Array value
> must start with "{" or dimension information.

This is the with subquery output.

```
with whatposition as (select position pos from users cross join lateral 
jsonb_array_elements(user_details->'userProfile') with ordinality arr(elem,position)
where display_ok=false)
select concat('ARRAY[''userProfile'',''',(select pos-1 from whatposition)::text,'''',',''DocumentDetails'']');
```

OUTPUT OF THE ABOVE SQL

> ARRAY['userProfile','0','DocumentDetails']

But when I pass the value as a literal to the above SQL it works just fine.

```
with whatposition as (select position pos from users cross join lateral 
jsonb_array_elements(user_details->'userProfile') with ordinality arr(elem,position)
where display_ok=false)
update users set user_details=jsonb_set(
user_details,ARRAY['userProfile','0','DocumentDetails'],'[{"y":"cccValue"}]')
where display_ok=false;
```

Comment: Please explain what the query is supposed to achieve exactly. The current query logic is broken beyond the superficial syntax error. If the CTE returns multiple rows (as expected), the ARRAY constructor will fail because the nested subselect is only allowed to return a single value in this place.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the `ARRAY[…]` syntax in a literal value.

```
with whatposition as (
  select position pos
  from users
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(user_details->'Profile') with ordinality arr(elem,position)
  where display_ok=false
)
update users
set user_details=jsonb_set(
  user_details,
  ARRAY['userProfile', (select pos-1 from whatposition)::text, 'DocumentDetails'],
  '[{"y":"supernewValue"}]'
)
where display_ok=false;
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi and Erwin. I assumed the update was valid JSON since postgres SQL did not give error. After your comments, I checked to discover that the JSON format was invalid. Thanks for your suggestion. it greatly helped.

Answer (score 0):

The query you are trying is broken beyond the superficial syntax error (which is [addressed by Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69783475/939860)).

If the CTE returns multiple rows (as expected), the ARRAY constructor will fail because the nested subselect is only allowed to return a single value in this place.

To "upsert" (insert or update) the property `"DocumentDetails": [{"y": "cccValue"}]}` to the first element (the one with subscript `0`) of the nested JSON array `user_details->'userProfile'`:

#### Postgres 14 or later

Make use of [JSONB subscripting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSONB-SUBSCRIPTING):

```sql
UPDATE users
SET    user_details['userProfile'][0]['DocumentDetails'] = '[{"y":"cccValue"}]'
WHERE  display_ok = FALSE;
```

#### Postgres 13

[Use `jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) - exactly like you already have in your last code example, only without the unneeded CTE:

```sql
UPDATE users
SET    user_details = jsonb_set(user_details, '{userProfile, 0, DocumentDetails}', '[{"y":"cccValue"}]')
WHERE  display_ok = FALSE;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e19b9d427080dd19c231bfee89ee527a)*

Comment: @bergi - I thought of giving a simple example of the before and after JSON <br/> 'code` {
 "userProfile": [{
  "profileName": "staff"
                 },
                {
                 "profileName": "manager"
                },
  {
                 "profileName": "executive"
  }]
} **after update** {
 "userProfile": [{
  "profileName": "staff",
  "kycDocumentDetails": [{
   "y": "cccValue"
  }],
                {
                 "profileName": "manager"
                },
  {
                 "profileName": "executive"
                }

 }]
}

Comment: I don't want to add to every element. Just the one position "0".

Comment: @tenettestuser1: What you show as "after update" isn't valid JSON. To add `just the one position "0"` isn't clear either. Also, your comment isn't reaching bergi under my answer. Please [edit] your question to show what you want.